# Use enum as a function parameter

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I'm making a function that takes an enum as a parameter which contains every month of the year. I made this work without a function, but that was not the idea.

The function should work with a switch statement, so that if I use September, the function should return a 9, if I input May it should return 5, etc.

I'm using the IBM Swift Sandbox and it gives me the following error:

> /swift-execution/Sources/main.swift:129:1: warning: result of call tonumeroMes(mes:)' is unused numeroMes(mes:.Septiembre)

Here's my enum:

```
enum meses {
    case Enero
    case Febrero
    case Marzo
    case Abril
    case Mayo
    case Junio
    case Julio
    case Agosto
    case Septiembre
    case Octubre
    case Noviembre
    case Diciembre
}
```

And the function that is not working:

```
func numeroMes(mes: meses) -> Int {
    switch mes {
        case .Enero:
            return 1
        case .Febrero:
            return 2
        case .Marzo:
            return 3
        case .Abril:
            return 4
        case .Mayo:
            return 5
        case .Junio:
            return 6
        case .Julio:
            return 7
        case .Agosto:
            return 8
        case .Septiembre:
            return 9
        case .Octubre:
            return 10
        case .Noviembre:
            return 11
        case .Diciembre:
            return 12 
    }
}

numeroMes(mes:.Septiembre)
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's just a warning that you're not using the result of the function call

Comment: As a side note, convention states that types should be `UpperCamelCase`, therefore your enum should be called `Meses`.

Comment: Oh that's right, I put the last line inside a print and it worked. However is the first enum used as a parameter in the function?

Comment: Adding to Hamish comment and the enum  cases should start with a lowercase letter (Swift 3 beta 6)

Comment: Lowercasing proper nouns seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a warning not an error. It's simply saying that the result of the call to `numeroMes` is not used.

Incidentally, it looks like you can use a raw type for the enumeration instead of defining a custom conversion function. Here's how

```
enum Mese: Int {
    case Enero = 1
    case Febrero
    case Marzo
    case Abril
    case Mayo
    case Junio
    case Julio
    case Agosto
    case Septiembre
    case Octubre
    case Noviembre
    case Diciembre
}
```

The other values will increment from `1`, so `Febrero` is `2`, `Marzo` is `3` and so on.

Now whenever you need to retrieve the raw value from an enum, just call `rawValue` on it. Example:

```
Mese.Febrero.rawValue // 2
```